# dashboard layout with multiple column on header and footer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using grids for admin dashboard. The design I am trying is there will be two column on header where on the left there will be a logo and the right one will be responsible for something like menu bar. The second row will be of sidebar and main body. The last row will be the footer but on the left it should have setting or logout button which should be fixed. I tried but i could not divide the header and footer into two column.

here is what I am trying to do. I hope it will be clear what i am trying to say

```css
.dashboard {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    header {
     background: blue;
     grid-column: 1/-1;
     grid-row: 1;
    }
    
    aside {
      background-color: #00152b;
      grid-row:2/3;
      grid-column:1;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    main {
      background: #acacd71c;
      grid-row: 2;
      grid-column: 2;
    }
    
    footer {
      grid-row: 4;
      grid-column:2;
    }
    
    .fixed-logout-btn {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      background: blue;
      display: flex;
      width: 180px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <header>
    <div class="left">
      logo
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      menu bar
    </div>
  </header>
  <aside>
    <p>aside</p>
    <div class="fixed-logout-btn">
      <p>logout</p>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <p>main</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>copyright</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

This is the expected one

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works for you.  I don't think you were containing your menu bar correctly the `.right` class.

```css
.dashboard {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
      grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    
    header {
     background: blue;
     grid-column: 1/-1;
     grid-row: 1;
    }
    
    aside {
      background-color: #00152b;
      color: grey;
      grid-row:2/3;
      grid-column:1;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    main {
      background: #acacd71c;
      grid-row: 2;
      grid-column: 2;
    }
    
    footer {
      grid-row: 4;
      grid-column:2;
    }
    
    .fixed-logout-btn {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      background: yellow;
      display: flex;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    .right {
      grid-row: 1;
      grid-column: 2;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <header>
    <div class="left">
      logo
    </div>
  </header>
    <div class="right">
      menu bar
    </div>
  <aside>
    <p>aside</p>
    <div class="fixed-logout-btn">
      <p>logout</p>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <main>
    <p>main</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>copyright</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. However, if i give padding on the footer and height on the menu bar then it breaks the design.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the issue with adding padding to the footer and height on the menu and it is acting as expected. can you screenshot or share a jsfiddle of the issue when doing so?

Comment: sorry footer is working fine but if i give height to .right class around 10px then the background color of header is shown

Comment: Change your `grid-column: 1/-1;` to `grid-column: 1;` in the header. this should fix your issue.